# How to send a mail to new registered user with a link to change password?

Tags: django

The user submit a form with his name, email, etc. This form is submitted and it creates the user account and it sets a random password.

How can I send to each new user a mail with a link to change **directly** the password ; I mean without the *password_reset_form.html* step.

Put concisely, I wish to send a mail with

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

but I get this :

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': '', 'token': ''}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']
```

**EDIT**

After passing the token and uid, the link in mail is not valid.

Here is the way I try to pass the **uid** and **token** to my function :

```
def password_mail(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_email = instance.email
        first_name = instance.first_name
        domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
        uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(instance.pk))
        token = token_generator.make_token(instance)



        text_content = render_to_string('accounts/mail_password.txt', {'first_name': first_name, 'domain': domain, 'uid': uid, 'token': token})
```

I am not getting this error anymore but the link provided is not a validlink.

Comment: This should work as long as you pass `token` and `uid` into the context that's rendering your email. Look at your error, `uid` and `token` are empty strings that's why the url reverse matcher can't get the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Please pass **uid** and **token** as context variables to the above given template.

Comment: I have edited the post, trying to following your advice. I am missing something.

Comment: Still getting the same error, and what is instance.password ?

Comment: It is no more used. I have edited the post to delete this.
I am not getting the same error but the link provided is not a validlink.

Comment: Can you add a sample link here ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a link to send you, this project si quite confidential.

In the password_reset_confirm.html template, if I delete the validlink tag, I have got no form. Maybe it can help to figure it out...